# FontAwesome Not Loading for Client

Tags: css, font-awesome, firewall

I'm currently using the CDN url and JS to fallback to local copy of the CSS file. In both cases our client isn't able to see the icons, just squares. "Our new firewall does packet inspection" is what the client says.

He is able to, however, go directly to the CSS file via the CDN URL without any issues; yet the icons will not show up. Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: I'd be interested in what the user's browser console is spitting out.

Comment: What specifically should I ask them to screenshot?

Comment: Maybe the client has a content blocker for webfonts?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the simplest thing to explain. For Chrome, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console, for Firefox, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console. Chances are there's a message in it that indicates why fonts aren't loading.

Comment: You can try a remote viewer such as teamviewer ( https://www.teamviewer.com/en/ ) for secure connective viewing (and control) of what the client sees on their machine.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is should they send screenshots of the Network tab, Console?

Comment: Console and Network are both potentially useful.

Comment: Client whitelisted the CDN URL ... working now. Thanks folks